# SQL Query that returns parent records regardless if child records are present

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need help constructing a query that returns parent records (from the Meeting table), regardless if the child records are present (from the ActionItems table). I was able to do this with a LEFT JOIN, but once I added other associated tables (Members and Category), the code wouldn't work.

Here is the structure of my tables:

[image]

I need to display information from each Meeting

1. The CategoryId field might be blank in the ActionItems Table, I need to show ActioItem even if CategoryId is blank
2. Meeting might not have any Action Items associated with it, need to return Meeting records even if there are no ActionItems

Here's my code that doesn't work (I may need to make multiple queries which is fine):

```
SELECT  Members.FirtName
        , Members.LastName
        , Meeting.Notes
        , Meeting.Location
        , ActionItems.Details
        , ActionItems.CompleteByDate
        , Category.Name
FROM    Members INNER JOIN 
            (Meetings LEFT JOIN 
                (ActionItems INNER JOIN Category.Id = ActionItems.CategoryId) 
             ON Meeting.Id = ActionItems.MeetingId) 
        ON Members.Id = Meeting.MemberId;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when using `LEFT JOIN`, they need to be chained -- that is, all the joins should be outer joins.

Try this:

```
SELECT mem.FirtName, mem.LastName, m.Notes, m.Location, ai.Details, 
ai.CompleteByDate, c.Name
FROM ((Meetings as m LEFT JOIN
       ActionItems as ai 
       ON m.Id = ai.MeetingId Members
      ) LEFT JOIN
      Category as c
      ON c.Id = ai.CategoryId
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Members mem
     ON mem.Id = m.MemberId;
```

That said, if there are multiple action items for the meeting, then each member will be duplicated for each action item.

Answer (score 1):

All the join on the same "branch" must be left till the end of the chain. So in this case all what joined to ActionItems need to be left join. 
Your select should be working like this:

```
SELECT  Members.FirtName
        , Members.LastName
        , Meeting.Notes
        , Meeting.Location
        , ActionItems.Details
        , ActionItems.CompleteByDate
        , Category.Name
FROM    Members INNER JOIN 
            (Meetings LEFT JOIN 
                (ActionItems LEFT JOIN Category.Id = ActionItems.CategoryId) 
             ON Meeting.Id = ActionItems.MeetingId) 
        ON Members.Id = Meeting.MemberId;
```